# Problems with React.createElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to reproduce [this](http://sahatyalkabov.com/create-a-character-voting-app-using-react-nodejs-mongodb-and-socketio/) tutorial (it's outdated a bit) and at this place

`var html = ReactDOM.renderToString(React.createElement(Router.RouterContext, renderProps));`

I'm get this error:

`Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).`

Error triggered by

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
let history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={history}>
        {routes}
    </Router>, 
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I'm newbie at React so maybe you can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Right after that sections there is an update:

```
October 19, 2015 Update: Previous React.renderToString now lives
in the react-dom/server package. Additionally, server-side rendering
with    React Router has changed quite a bit. See Server Rendering
Guide for more details.
```

It looks like you'll need to set it up according to their Server Rendering Guide.

Comment: Yes, I checked it. Unfortunately, that guide isn't suitable for me. I need to find solution for `React.createElement()`

Comment: In that case I would look for a more recent tutorial that's not as complex as that one